# Why do we need default constructor when we can initialize data members in java?

Tags: java, constructor

My question is, when we declare a java class with data members we normally initialize them using constructors(With an exception to static members). But the data members can also be initialized directly without calling the constructor.

```
public class Box {
      public int height = 0;
      public int width = 0;
}
```

When this is possible, why do we need a default constructor? like this

```
public Box(){
      height = 0;
      width = 0;
}
```

The memory for an object is created when it is instantiated. But if memory for data members are allocated while creating objects then how is it possible to initialize data members at the beginning of the class?

Comment: The situation that you have presented does not require a default constructor. That being said, there are plenty of situations where the values are not known until the default constructor is called.

Comment: The other reason you might need a no-argument constructor is that if `YourClass` has another constructor that takes arguments, a client cannot say `new YourClass()` with no arguments, unless you explicitly add a no-argument constructor.

Comment: You don't *need* a default ctor until you do. For example, many systems that use JavaBean convention require a default ctor so it can instantiate objects without parameters.

Comment: default constructors initializes data members with values specified by the programmer right? parameterized constructors may have different values at run time. But defaut constructors does not behave like the parameterized ones right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a simple case where you can initialize the data members, as in your example, you don't need a default constructor.

However you might want to do more things in a default constructor than initialize some fields;

**Call a non-default constructor of the super class:**

```
public class Box extends Shape {
      public int height = 0;
      public int width = 0;

      public Box() {
         super("Box");
}
```

**Do some work as part of the constructor :**

```
public class Boxes {
     private HashMap<String, Box> boxes = new HashMap<String, Box>();

      public Boxes() {
         boxes.put("2x2", new Box(2,2));
         boxes.put("4x4", new Box(4,4));
         ....
}
```

**Provide a non-default constructor as well as a default constructor.**

If you create a non-default constructor, there will not be a default constructor created automatically.

```
public class Box {
      public int height;
      public int width;

      public Box() {
         height = 0;
         width = 0;
         //or simply call Box(0,0)
      }
      public Box(int height, int width) {
         this.height = heigth;
         this.width = width;
      }
}
```

without code for the  no-argument `Box()` constructor, you can't do `new Box()` since there is a `Box(int height, int width)` constructor. However if you don't write any constructors, the compiler creates the no-argument `Box()` constructor for you.

Answer (score 0):

You don't specifically need a default constructor if your class doesn't have other constructors and an external framework (or probably your own code) could create instances of it and needs to use the default constructor.

Some examples:

- Jackson for JSON deserialization using `ObjectMapper#readValue`
- JSF when creating managed beans

If you don't have this scenario, then you don't even need to add a default constructor, the compiler will do it for you.

Answer (score 0):

You will need constructor to execute more complex operations than just initializing with a constant value. For example you want to dynamically pass an object in to another class while creating instance. A simple documentation can be found [here](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~matuszek/General/JavaSyntax/constructors.html)

Answer (score 0):

Constructor is meant to initialize an object, to add some state, to make the object ready for use before we start calling methods on it. Initializing an object can be anything like setting some values for instance variables other than the default values, or adding items to an ArrayList or Map to use those values in the methods defined in that class.

For better understanding, I recommend you to refer to this link - [Class and Object Initialization](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2075796/java-platform/java-101--class-and-object-initialization.html)